# Laravel: how to get direct config value in blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i want to get config value in blade.

```
config/define.php
<?php
return [
    'show' => array(1 => 'Show',0 => 'Hide' ),
];
```

I found a code

```
{{ Config::get('define.show') }}
```

But i want use:

```
{{ $showarray = Config::get('define.show') }}

@foreach ($master as $pt)
{{ $showarray[$pt->show_flag] }}
@endforeach
```

But it does not work. Help me please!

Comment: Just remember that `{{ }}` is interpolation, meaning, it is used for printing values. It isn't a section of PHP code where you could do processing.

Comment: `{{ }}` code is the same meaning as `<?php echo " "?>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it by -

```
@foreach ($master as $pt)
    {{ Config::get('define.show.' . $pt->show_flag) }} // concatenate the value
@endforeach
```

Or by using `@php` tag -

```
@php
    $showarray = Config::get('define.show');
@endphp

@foreach ($master as $pt)
    {{ $showarray[$pt->show_flag] }}
@endforeach
```

You can also access the configs by using `config()`.

Comment: `{{ Config::get('define.show.' . $pt->show_flag) }}`are you sure that first approach will work?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes.if the values are proper. You can try it on your own.

Comment: <?php
    $showarray = Config::get('define.show');
?>

it's worked, Thanks so much